# Not able to assign view variable in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, spree

I have the custom method in my ProductsController of my spree app.

```
module Spree
  module Api
    class ProductsController < Spree::Api::BaseController

      def custom_view 
        @test = "This is test variable"
      end

    end
  end 
end
```

in my view custom_view.html.erb i have the following

```
<h1>Custom View Title</h1>
<p>test : <%= @test %></p>
```

The rendering gives the following output:

Custom View Title

test :

Obviously the variable is not being transmitted from the controller.
I have tried to add before_filer methods and added `puts "debug" custom view` in the method but neither the before_filter seem to be executing nor the puts output is showing in the log.

Am i doing something wrong ? How can i pass view variables in that case ?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have tried to replace

```
module Spree
  module Api
    class ProductsController < Spree::Api::BaseController
```

by

```
Spree::Api::ProductsController.class_eval do
```

Only to end-up with the same results...

Comment: what does it render, if you write: `<p>test : <%= @test.inspect %></p>`?

Comment: Why are you doing this in the API namespace? Shouldn't you be doing this in the regular app?

Comment: NickM: I need to benefit from any before_filter that is used in ProductsController ( @product, images and whatever need to be fetched before i can populate my custom view for a certain product )

Comment: @canc : the output is `test: nil`

Comment: @RailsRails are you sure the method `custom_view` is executed? I guess rails does not pick your controller at all. Make sure your request is routed to the controller.